# What's different in women's specific chamois cream?

Tags: women-specific, chamois-creme

What's the difference between regular chamois cream and women specific chamois cream?  If my partner also rides, are there disadvantages to both male and female users sharing the women specific type?

Comment: I've never seen a "women specific" cream.

Comment: See Chamois Butt'r Her', DZ Nutz Bliss, and Hoo Ha Ride Glide

Comment: Pick up a bottle of each and compare the ingredients lists.

Comment: I wonder if the difference might be in fragrance or color, or even just the packaging?

Comment: Love the "partner ... female ... userS".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In many cases, the difference is just related to the scent.

However, some standard chamois cream has menthol or some other "icy hot" chemical, which some women find a bit "strong" for their sensitive bits.  Many women's creams use something milder, like peppermint oil.

Mad Alchemy lists some of the major ingredients in their chamois creams:
http://www.madalchemy.com/

Comment: I've seen other ingredients that tend to be in women's specific products where it's less frequently found in others such as shea butter, tea-tree oil, and probiotic bacteria lactobacillius (seen in DZ Nutz Bliss).

Answer (score -3):

There shouldn't be any difference but I believe that the slight difference is nothing more than an antiseptic.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Tom. We are looking for definite answers, rather than chat or discussion. When you have enough [rep](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) such a post should be made as a comment.